# CSS selectors on active elements by id

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am working on a personal website using a template and have run into an issue with something I am trying to do. As it stands the following is working:

```
<nav id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#top" id="top-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-home">Introduction</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" id="about-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-male">About Me</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#resume" id="resume-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-star">Resumé</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects" id="resume-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-heart">Current Projects</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#skills" id="skills-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-th">Skills & Hobbies</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" id="contact-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-paper-plane">Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

With the following css:

```
#nav ul li a.active span:before
{
    color: green;
}
```

However I would like to make it so that each  has a different colour when active. I am struggling with selecting the  in css by ID while also making sure it is active.

i.e. about-link will be color: red when active, resume-link will be color: blue when active etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI you duplicated the ID `resume-link` in your example.

Comment: `#resume-link.active span:before { color: blue; }`?

Comment: @RobPio that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have IDs, use them directly since they are unique:

```
nav ul li a {
    color: black; /* common unactive color */
}

#about-link.active {
    color: red;
}

#resume-link.active {
    color: blue;
}
```

etc...

If you want the same effect for hover states and active class, you can do:

```
#about-link:hover, #about-link.active {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following class CSS selector. Make sure on each page you regulate what link has the "active" class:

http://jsfiddle.net/clarketm/6ksmj8wv/2/

```
#about-link.active {
    color: red;
}

#resume-link.active {
    color: blue;
}
```